# Liquibase - apply changeSet to DB2 for iSeries: case sensitive?

Tags: db2, liquibase

I have the following problem with Liquibase 3.3. I use liquibase-db2i extension to update a DB2 for iSeries database. All the existing table names in my schema are in uppercase. The table names in my generated changeSet are in lowercase. If I execute "liquibase update" with my changelog I get the following error:

```
Change Set changelog.xml::1::user (generated) failed.
Error: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0204] test_table in TESTSCHEMA type *FILE not found.
```

If I manually convert the table names in the changeSet to uppercase no error occurs and the database is updated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting. I was going to say, "It works OK for me," but then I realised that all the table names in my generated changeset are already in upper case. They're also quoted: `<createTable tableName="AUDITS">`. Which of course they have to be, as XML attributes.

I would guess, though, that the quotes are being passed through to the generated SQL, which would cause the effect that you're seeing. It might be worth running `liquibase ... updateSQL`, and having a look, though.

It should be easy enough to change the liquibase-db2i extension to include Java `toUpperCase` calls everywhere. I'm not sure whether it would be worth the trouble, though, when you can just specify the names as upper case.